# Libgdx skin issue

Tags: java, libgdx

I use a skin for my game. I use the drawable from the skin to make an Image object. I need 2 copies of this image - one rotated by 180degrees, and another one, not rotated. But when I rotate one copy of the image, the second one gets rotated too:

```
Image img1 = new Image(skin, "drawableName");
stage.addActor(img1);
Image img2 = new Image(skin, "drawableName");
img2.setRotation(180);
stage.addActor(img2);
```

Outcome is, two images are rotated by 180 degrees. Can someone tell me why it happens, and how should i use the skin to make different copies of the same image?

Comment: Probably cause they both point to the same drawable. Try creating an Image with a new TextureRegion (using a different Image constructor) to ensure that each image gets a unique drawable.

Comment: I checked the source, and that's not it. Drawables do not store any rotation parameter. Is this your exact code, or is it possible you have a typo in the original?